# Keycloak: Not able to search system generated service account user in Users

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

`Keycloak version: 20.0.3`

Docker command: `docker run --name keycloak -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.1 start-dev`

Performed Steps :

1. Login to keycloak.
2. Create a new realm.
3. create a client in `Clients` with name ***system_user_demo_service*** with config `client authentication: On`, `Authorization: On` and `Authentication flow: Standard Flow, Direct access grants`.
4. Go to `Users`.

I can see a user got created with name ***service-account-system_user_demo_service***. But when I am searching with this username, It is saying **No search results**`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because it is not a user, it is a Client Service account and Keycloak hide them for security purpose.

[Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/) says :

```
A client’s service account is a user account with username service-account-CLIENT_ID. You can perform the same user operations on this account as a regular account.
```

Comment: So, there is no way to search for a service account in `Users`?

Comment: Nope, and it is not made to be used as a user it is a  SERVICE-account, so depending of what you want to do with you will prefer to create a user.

Comment: Mark this as an answer if it is ok for you please ;)

Comment: However GET `/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}` where `id` is service account user id, returns that user. So they are not users, but they are users.